# Is there a component for .NET to create ControlPanel-style layout with icons?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

Is there a component for .NET WinForms or WPF to create a ControlPanel-style layout with icons?
 I want to have a window which looks like a Control Panel and have a variable number of icons in it.

Comment: The UniformGrid or WrapPanel might be what you are looking for.

Comment: It is a Winforms ListView.  View = Tiles or LargeIcon or SmallIcon, depending on the "View by" selection you pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
<UniformGrid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image Width="48" 
                Height="48" 
                Source="appbar.forklift.load.png" />
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Hyperlink>Action Center</Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image Width="48" 
                Height="48" 
                Source="appbar.forrst.png" />
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Hyperlink>Keyboard</Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image Width="48" 
                Height="48" 
                Source="appbar.forklift.png" />
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Hyperlink>Notification</Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image Width="48" 
                Height="48" 
                Source="appbar.forklift.load.png" />
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Hyperlink>Region</Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image Width="48" 
                Height="48" 
                Source="appbar.forklift.load.png" />
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Hyperlink>Speech</Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>       
</UniformGrid>
```

You can add as many as you want they will be layed out for you. (A wrappanel might be better depending on what you really want).

You could then bind the "Command" property of each link to a command on your ViewModel
if you are using MVVM.

```
<HyperLink Command="{Binding OpenActionLinkCenterCommand}">Action Center</HyperLink>
```

If you want the items to come from a Collection, you can use an ItemsContainer or ListBox
and change the ItemsPanel template

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourControlPanelItems}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Of course there are many more ways of doing it, this is just a small example.

Comment: Do we have anything for 3.5?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? As those controls have been in there since the first versions

Comment: Yep, sorry, I've figured it out :)